# Histogram of dates in Google Sheets or OpenOffice

Tags: openoffice, spreadsheet, google-drive, google-spreadsheets

I have a list of dates that I would like create a histogram of.

```
date
5/21/2014
5/20/2014
9/16/2014
5/28/2014
6/8/2014
6/8/2014
5/28/2014
5/20/2014
8/11/2014
7/19/2014
8/11/2014
```

The chart's x-axis would be dates, the y-axis would be number of occurrences. Is this possible to do with Google Sheets or OpenOffice?

Comment: http://wikieducator.org/OpenOffice/Calc_3/Histogram

Comment: Possible, yes.  Practical, maybe not.  I believe you'd need to use one of the sorting and filtering methods from [this tutorial](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=75&t=38056) to get a sorted list of dates without duplicates, and then use the COUNTIF function in an adjacent column to get the number of occurrences.  Then you could graph the list of dates with associated numbers of occurrences.